# simple structs with make_unique and emplace_back

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, emplace

Given a struct:

```
struct S {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Why the Standard allows us to do this:

```
std::vector<S> vec;
vec.emplace_back(1, 2);
```

But does not allow to do this:

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<S>(1, 2);
```

?

Comment: Works fine with me http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c54feda67017bf1
(I had to add a constructor to the struct but that's all)

Comment: No, both are [not allowed](http://rextester.com/WBNIK94302). If you provide a ctor (`S::S(int, int)`) then both are [fine](http://rextester.com/UHFEW17433).

Comment: @Pumkko I meant exactly simple struct without ctor :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check your code.

In cpp14 your example code doesn't compile: https://ideone.com/ewyHW6

Both `make_unique` and `emplace_back` are using `std::forward<Args>(args)...` in background, so either both or none compiles.

Comment: @vladon nobody's perfect. Mistakes happen :-)

Answer (score 10):

Actually neither work.

It was decided that emplace-style construct functions in C++ `std` would construct with `()`s not `{}`s.  There is no *strong* reason why this was chosen (that I know of).

`emplace_alt` snd `make_unique_alt` could be added to `std` where it constructs using `{}` instead.  (a better name should be chosen, naturally)

So the short answer is "because `std` says so".  The medium answer is "it is a near arbitrary choice made by `std`, followed elsewhere to be consistent".  The long answer would involve being in the room where it happened and where it was revisited: this is not a long answer.

Answer (score 2):

After 8 years from the original post, they both seem to work!

With clang 16.0.0 and later, and c++20: https://godbolt.org/z/4aaaaf6aW

And with gcc 10.2 and later: https://godbolt.org/z/c6hbd5E86

Answer (score 0):

how about

`auto ptr = std::make_unique<S>( S{1, 2} );`

without defining an extra ctor with args.

Comment: this doesn't work ...